# Cannot read pandas library in my module when calling from my script

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry about the title. Wasn't sure how to frame the question, though it is pretty short.

I created a module called phase_2 which is used to generate some dates, including the date of today.

```
class phase_2():
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import datetime as dt
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import yfinance as yf
    import talib
    import time

    ## in phase we define all the dates
    def today():
        today = pd.to_datetime(dt.datetime.now()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        return today
```

I then created a test script trying to get the date of today by calling the function in the module:

```
from phase_2 import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
import talib
import time
import pyodbc

print(phase_2.today())
```

This returns me the error:
"name 'pd' is not defined"

How is this possible given that I define it twice? Both in the module and in my testing script.

Here is the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
import talib
import time

class phase_2():
 
## in phase we define all the dates
    def today():
        today = pd.to_datetime(dt.datetime.now()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        return today
```

```
from phase_2 import *


print(phase_2.today())
```

Comment: Because you can't put `import` statements in a class like that.  Move them out to global level.  Alternatively, you could say `today = self.pd.to_datetime(...)`, but that's very non-Pythonic.

Comment: moved the libs out to the global level and it worked. thanks :)